# Keeping ASP.NET4.0 page warm on shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, shared-hosting, warm-up

I have a (yet) rarely visited page deployed on a shared hosting environment. Currently, I get very low number of visitors, like 1 visitor/day.

It looks like that IIS 7.0 "drops" my site after being idle too long. The first pageload after this takes 30 seconds or more. **Due to the rare visits, actually all my visitors pay for the site-startup**. 
(After reviving the site, the page load normalizes to 1-3 seconds.)

I know about Application Warm-Up features of ASP.NET4.0 and IIS7.5, but due to the given shared hosting environment, I have no way to utilize them.

How can I keep my site artificially alive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fire up a timer in your `Global.asax` and make it poke itself by "visiting" several pages via simple `WebRequest`.

Comment: I like this better than having to sign up for a service. Great Idea.

Comment: The service is nice because it also can give you a buzz if your site is down.

Comment: Any details on this? Maybe a blog post that describes the exact steps with code samples?

Answer (score 5):

Try the free account on: http://www.montastic.com/
You just enter in your url and tell it to visit it every 30 mins.

This will keep your site up

Comment: Assuming 30 minutes isn't too long an interval, that should work :)